# How to Fix "android.app.RemoteServiceException" in android

Tags: java, android, service, crash, remoteserviceexception

I got crash on the play console on android 8.1 or the upper version devices.
Here is my crash log.

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1970)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7386)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:980)
```

I am using the ForegroundService in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error but i resolved it by
starting service using `startForegroundService()`
instead of `startService()`